# How to get a non-equally spaced FFT back into the time domain

Tags: fourier-transform

I have a signal that I STFT and then filter using an ERB spaced filterbank. At some point after this I want to get the signal back into the time domain, how can I go about this? Using a standard iSTFT function won't work because it assumed linearly spaced frequency bins, AFAIK? I've put a code snippet below.

I'm also not sure what what to tag this question as apart from `fourier-transform`

````
Y = stft(sig) # Y.shape = (1025,4000)
fb = filterbank() # fb.shape = (20,1025)

Y_erb = matrix_multiply(fb,Y) # Y_erb.shape = (20,4000)
```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that you can solve a least squares problem with the input signal as the decision variables.

#### About Nonequispaced FFT

There is a [related question in stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67350588/example-python-nfft-fourier-transform-issues-with-signal-reconstruction-normal).

If you are not using python, you can take a look into the [nfft github](https://github.com/NFFT/nfft).

[Here](https://www-user.tu-chemnitz.de/%7Epotts/paper/nfft3.pdf) will find some information. Section 4.6 covers the inversion of such transforms.